# Populate HTML with database data

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I've come across a few questions like mine, however, each seemed to have a very different answer, so it still keeps me wondering.

I want to populate my HTML with data from my database.

I have the following view:

```
@extends('layouts.base')

@section('title', 'Home')

@section('body')
    @include('includes.navbar')

    <div class="container">
        <div class="some-class">DATABASE DATA HERE</div>
        <div class="some-class">DATABASE DATA HERE</div>
        <div class="some-class">DATABASE DATA HERE</div>
        <div class="some-class">DATABASE DATA HERE</div>
        <div class="some-class">DATABASE DATA HERE</div>
    </div>

    @include('includes.footer')
@stop
```

I have the following route:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('index');
});
```

How would I populate the view with data from the database (**preferably using Eloquent ORM**)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a broad question but you need to create the `Eloquent` model first, for example:

```
class MyModel extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'tablename';
}
```

Then you have this:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('index');
});
```

In that function, you can query and pass the data to your view, like:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    $records = MyModel::all(); // get all records
    return View::make('index')->with('records', $records); // Pass $records to view
});
```

Then in your `View`, you may use a loop if there are multiple records, for example:

```
@foreach($records as $record)
    {{ $record->field }}
@endforeach
```

Well, this may help you to get the idea. You may [read more here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent).

Comment: What if I need data from multiple sets of tables? Would I just create another model and then call it within the route again (i.e. `$another = AnotherModel.all();`)? It seems like the route could get quite big. Are there ways to organize it better?

Comment: Yes, you may use `Controller` classes instead of an `Anonymous` function and also keep your logic in a different service class/model. If you want to use `Eloquent` then yes for different table, you need to create another `Eloquent` model and don't use any logic (No Eloquent query) in the `View`.